# Pylint ignore-patterns Not Working

Tags: regex, pylint

I'm using an rc file that has:

`ignore-patterns=".*local.*"`

I expect this to ignore all files with the word `local` in the name.  So, `tmplocal.py`, `tmp.local.py`, `tmp_local.py`, `local_tmp.py`, etc.

When running Pylint (1.7.2), these files are *not* ignored.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `ignore-patters="^(?!.*local)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No luck.  Same problem.  :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What ended up working for me was not including quotes. My current config looks something like this: `ignore-patterns=one.py,.*local.*`

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 1.7.2, 
astroid 1.5.3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```